# Correct way of storing custom text wrapped with styles - Database or Text File?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am running ASP.NET connecting to a SQL Server 2005 database.

Currently all my data get's saved in the database but when I use my HTML editor control (to allow the user to add styles to the text) sometimes I get the following error when I copy text with lots of styles from another website into the text area (error comes up when data is trying to save to database):

> String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.

Why is this and how do I handle this? Save the text rather to a text file?

The size of the field in the database is big enough!

***Edits***

```
INSERT INTO TableName(Name, Age, Comments) VALUES (@Name, @Age, @Comments)
```

Then from my code behind I simply call my SQLDatasource like so

```
SqlDataSource.Insert()
```

Comment: Also, what code are you using to add this to your database? Perhaps that is where the problem is.

Comment: "big enough" - there is enough space in the column to take all the text with the tags <br>text</b>

Comment: Second question - I am saving it with a SQLDataSource - SqlDataSource.Insert()

Comment: I meant show more code than that. Show the query you are using. The building and execution of that query, any SQL side code (e.g. stored procs), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are passing a string variable to a stored procedure whit p.e. varchar(250) and the string length is over 251, even if the field in the table is varchar(1025) you'll get the error because of the param length is not ok.

Or... Try to use "text" type on db field?

It's an idea, if you get more info we'll be more usefull. :)

Comment: That's the kind of thing I was getting at with the "show code" comment above. If things like parameters on the C# side or on the SQL side are set incorrectly it might be causing problems.

Comment: Yes I am passing a string variable of say varchar(400) into my database where the column size is varchar(4500)

Comment: "even if the field in the table is varchar(1025) you'll get the error because of the param length is not ok." - what do you mean??

Comment: You are passing three parameters @Name, @Age, and @Comments. If they are defined as varchar(450) instead of varchar(4500) then you could have problems there. Also, I still don't see where your SQL Query is being set up after your edits. I just see two disconnected lines of source code.

Comment: I don't set anything up(no code written), this get's done for you when you use a SQLDataSource

Comment: http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/using-parameterized-queries-with-the-sqldatasource-vb

Comment: Anyway the error means: you're trying to put a long sotring in a sort place. You've got the variable, the parameter and the db field (i suppouse there's no triggers or another store procedure/function running). One of that must have a different length and SQL must truncate the string.

Comment: @Daniel, the code on button submit is - SqlDataSource.Insert()

Comment: I see, then the length of the string you try to insert must be bigger than the length of the db char field, and de SQL has to truncate it.